# Font Size in SQL Results To Grid View in Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, settings

I'm working with VS21017 and I have a SQL file (scripts.sql) in my solution. When I open that file, I can connect to a database and execute queries.

The results grid for a typical SELECT statement is in a really small font.

I've looked in the Tools > Options menu under the Database Tools and SQL Server Tools headings, but can not find a way to increase/adjust the size of the font in that results grid. I have also tried various keyboard shortcuts that affect other places in VS, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd><</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>></kbd>, which work in C#, HTML, and T-SQL editors.

How can I adjust the size of the font in that results grid?

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Found it:

Tools>Options>Environment>Fonts and Colors

Show Settings For>"SQL Results - Grid"

Comment: Very Cool. Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me, however still looking for the Fonts/Colors settings for T-SQL "Messages" but using the screen magnifier is a temporary workaround sigh...